# Retrofit and OkHttp POST return bad request error 400

Tags: android, authentication, post, retrofit, okhttp

In my api package

```
public interface ApiCall {


    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("message/save")
    Call<Repo> listRepos(@Header("authorization") String authorization , @Body EvreyId evreyId);
```

}

```
public class BaseParser<T> {

    @SerializedName("meta")
    private Meta mMeta;

    public Meta getMeta() {
        return mMeta;
    }

    public void setMeta(Meta meta) {
        mMeta = meta;
    }

    @SerializedName("data")
    private T mData;

    public T getData() {
        return mData;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess(){
        if(mMeta==null ) return false;
        return mMeta.isSuccess();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class  EvreyId  {

    @SerializedName("DeviceId")
    @Expose
    private int DeviceId;

    @SerializedName("TripId")
    @Expose

    private int TripId;

    public EvreyId(int deviceId, int tripId) {
        DeviceId = deviceId;
        TripId = tripId;
    }

    public int getDeviceId() {
        return DeviceId;
    }

    public void setDeviceId(int deviceId) {
        DeviceId = deviceId;
    }

    public int getTripId() {
        return TripId;
    }

    public void setTripId(int tripId) {
        TripId = tripId;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Meta {

    @SerializedName("code")
    private int mCode;
    @SerializedName("error_message")
    private String mMessage;
    @SerializedName("error_type")
    private String mErrorType;

    public Boolean isSuccess() {
        return mCode / 100 == 2;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return mCode;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        mCode = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return mMessage;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        mMessage = message;
    }

    public String getErrorType() {
        return mErrorType;
    }

    public void setErrorType(String errorType) {
        mErrorType = errorType;
    }
}


public class Repo extends BaseParser {


}
```

//in MainActivity

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()

                            .addHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+ Token)
                            .build();
                    return chain.proceed(newRequest);

                }
            }).build();



        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(client)
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();


        ApiCall service = retrofit.create(ApiCall.class);


        EvreyId evreyId=new EvreyId(deviceId,TripId);

        Call<Repo> repos = service.listRepos(authorization,evreyId);


        repos.enqueue(new Callback<Repo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Repo> call, retrofit2.Response<Repo> response) {

                Repo repo=response.body();

    try {

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "response ErrorType :"+response.errorBody().string());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
      catch (NullPointerException e){
      Log.e(TAG, "Null pointer error meta :"+e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();

      }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Repo> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG,"fail"+t.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

in my logcat i get 400 Bad Request and i use optional T in `baseparser` class {
where is my mistake???

Comment: what is your full url to fetching data.

Comment: what is 400 in getting error message

Comment: i see this in my logcat

Comment: response ErrorType :<html>
              <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
            <body bgcolor="white">
          <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
      <hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
       </body>
   </html>

Comment: url and token is correct i checked

Comment: your server is expecting data which is either not reaching there or it is not able to ignore extra data, 400 error means either you are sending wrong data, or server is expecting some other form of data..in some different key value pair.. Recheck your request bean from server as well as from client

Comment: thanks Ashwani i send device id and trip id and that's easy.but i have problem with response.server is ok.server send meta and data.my repo class maybe:| but i think use rxjava but little hard for me